# useReactVar in apolloLink cause cannot update component while rendering a diffrend component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, apollo-client

i use apollo client and react in project

i want appear loading indicator while network request, so i set react variables and change it inside apollo link

but it cause `cannot update component(Indicator) while rendering a diffrend component(component that call useQuery hook)`

- loadingLink.ts

```
import { ApolloLink } from '@apollo/client';
import { loadingVar } from 'gql/store/reactiveVariables';

export const loadingLink = new ApolloLink((operation, forward) => {
  loadingVar(true);

  return forward(operation).map(data => {
    loadingVar(false);

    return data;
  });
});
```

- loadingIndicator.ts

```
import React from 'react';
import { useReactiveVar } from '@apollo/client';
import { loadingVar } from 'gql/store/reactiveVariables';
import { Indicator } from './Indicator';

const LoadingIndicator: React.FC = () => {
  const loading = useReactiveVar(loadingVar);

  if (!loading) return null;

  return <Indicator />;
};

export default LoadingIndicator;
```

- error message

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RLN4r.png)

- BatchList.tsx

```
const BatchList = () => {
  const {data, error} = useQuery(~~~);

  if(error) return null;
  if(loading || !data) return null;

  return ~~~~
}
```

in [documentation](https://reactjs.org/blog/2020/02/26/react-v16.13.0.html#warnings-for-some-updates-during-render), they say should use useEffect hook but inside ApolloLink i can't use useEffect hook

How can i fix it